# libudev0 is not installed

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I was trying to install Reditr(Redit Client) but I get a message saying

```
$ sudo dpkg -i reditr_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 209739 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack reditr_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking reditr (3.0.0.0) over (3.0.0.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of reditr:
 reditr depends on libudev0 (>= 147); however:
  Package libudev0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package reditr (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 reditr
```

Can't install libudev0 as well

```
Reading state information... Done
Package libudev0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libudev0' has no installation candidate
```

Out of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.3.2 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20151209)]/ trusty contrib main non-free

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libudev0 && sudo dpkg -i reditr_amd64.deb`

Comment: just edited my question.....libudev0 is not available @heemayl

Comment: [edit] your question and add which release are you using, also add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @heemayl edited and added the output of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Ok..Do `sudo apt-get update` and then do `apt-cache policy libudev0`

Comment: @heemayl with `apt-cache policy libudev0` i get `libudev0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35219/discussion-between-abhimanyu-aryan-and-heemayl).

Comment: Was there no resolution found?

Comment: @Rishabh nope. I guess they haven't upgrading there app for a long time. Ask on Reddit app group for reditr. I don't use this app now

Answer (score 3):

How I solved the issue is that I went to packages repository online, and downloaded "libudev0.deb" file from below link:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/udev/

and installed using:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package
```

you may also use gdebi for this purpose.